# Generic list and duplicate records

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Using the generic `TList` collection: Is there some function that detects duplicate records or do I need to do a search on all records and check single field if duplicated or not?

Answer (score 10):

The generic TList has a Contains method that can be used to detect duplicates. But you have to call this yourself as there is no Duplicates property as there is for TStringList.

If your data can be compared with a binary compare then there is nothing more to do. Otherwise you need to supply a custom comparer.

Comment: IndexOf (or even better Contains in that case) for records only works when a binary compare can be done. If you for example have a string in that record you have to define your own comparer and pass it in when creating the list.

Comment: Is there any reason this does not answer your question?

Comment: In response to Stefan's comment, TList is generally used to store a list of objects, so IndexOf() and Contains() should work. If you're storing strings, then you may as well use TStringList and set the Duplicates property.